# Changing the display attribute nullifies opacity transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using JavaScript to change the opacity of an element with `transition: opacity 1s`, you expect the transition to take one second, which it does [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fevr48c6/):

```js
onload = e => {
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

  p.style.opacity = 1;
};
```

```css
p {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum...
</p>
```

However, if the element has `display: none` and you first change it to `display: initial` (in order to see it) before changing the opacity the transition no longer works, which you can see  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oeuLk5za/):

```js
onload = e => {
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

  p.style.display = "initial";
  p.style.opacity = 1;
};
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum...
</p>
```

Why is this?

Note: I am *not* using a transition on the display attribute and neither am I looking for a workaround for that.

Comment: What is the use case for `display: none;`? When `opacity` is set to zero the element is already not visible.

Comment: The use is to remove it from the document flow, which is not evident in this [mcve]. Regardless of what the use is, I wonder why this happens.

Comment: It happens because that is the way the spec is written. display is a toggle and as @AndrewL64 states, you cannot animate a toggle.

Comment: I am not transitioning the display attribute, for the second time.

Comment: An since you 'toggle' display on, you aren't animating the `opacity` either. That simple.

Comment: By the way, to include more than one snippet, just duplicate the `<snippet>` tags in the raw answer and place your snippet there.

Comment: The code snippets aren't really working; you can't see the transition. I'm not looking for a workaround.

Comment: @Gendarme Well, there is no non-workaround for this issue since you cant transition the `display` property. And it's fine if the Code Snippets don't run the transition. Atleast the codes aren't in external links and will be available for future readers who have the same issue. Cheers.

Comment: I. Am. Not. Transitioning. The. Display. Property.

Comment: But at the time the transition starts, the computed value of the display property is `none`. This means all the other properties are discarded because that's how powerful `display:none` is. So you need to tell the browser you did change the display property to something that won't make all other rules discarded, and the easiest is to [trigger a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) after you changed the css rule so that all the computed values get updated.

Comment: By giving in to whoever nagged you to use snippets, you've rendered your runnable examples nonsensical. Then @MartijnPieters's edit removes your acknowledgement that the examples are nonsensical, leaving the question pretty confusing. As is often the case, this would've been better with non-snippet code included in the question and jsfiddle links for runnable demos. A reluctant -1 because thanks to the combined efforts of all contributors this whole question seems kind of nonsensical now unless you recognise that Stack Snippets are broken or look into the revision history.

Comment: @markamery The JSFiddles are still there, and anyone could copy-paste the snippets into JSFiddle themselvles. The snippets seem broken yeah, perhaps I should add a P.S. to address that.

Comment: @Gendarme Oh yeah, so they are. Maybe just un-Snippet-ify the code in the question, then? No sense making it runnable if it doesn't actually work.

Comment: It is only the first snippet in the question that doesn't work. The second one works and the two in my answer also do.

Comment: @MarkAmery: My apologies if I made things worse here, but the 'edit' headers were confusing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that the transition happens (or tries to happen) during the process of the display attribute changing (meaning that it is still `none` and the transition thus doesn't work). The transition could technically have started while the element had `display: none` and became visible only when the process of changing it to `display: initial` had finished, since the transition is one whole second while the change of display attribute is a fraction thereof. But that is simply not the case, it seems.

It is possible to change the opacity of an element that has `display: none` before changing it to `display: initial` as you can see here so that is clearly not the problem:

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
p.style.opacity = 0.3;
p.style.display = "initial";
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum...
</p>
```

It is also possible to change it afterwards (of course), so that seems to only leave our hypothesis as the only possibilty.

To make sure that the first process has finished before you start the transition, you can use a small delay like this and voilà, it works:

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

p.style.display = "initial";
setTimeout(function() {
 p.style.opacity = 1;
},100);
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum...
</p>
```

Comment: Wow don't use `setInterval` here, you want this to fire once and only once. Also, better to trigger a synchronous reflow, e.g simply getting `p.offsetLeft` will do, though it is even better to do it only once per frame when we are sure everything is readied, so the best would be to hook this in a rAF callback that will get called just before the next paint `p.style.display = 'initial'; requestAnimationFrame( _ => { p.offsetLeft; p.style.opacity = '1'; })`

Answer (score 1):

**tldr:** You cannot use the `transition` property with the `display` property. And yes, you can't use the `transition` property on any other css property of an element whose's current `display` property is `none` either.

---

The cleanest workaround for this would be to simultaneously transition the `width` property and the `opacity` property together.

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/9w6Lcmfk/27/) to see how you can use the `width` and `height` property to replicate the `display:none` property of not letting the element take any space in the document flow.

*The `<span>` element is just for demonstrating how the `<p>` tag does not take any space while it's hidden.*

You can also check out the code in the following Snippet but as you mentioned, the transition doesn't work here for some weird reason.

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

p.style.width = "50%";
p.style.height = "auto";
p.style.opacity = 1;
```

```css
html, body{width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
p {
  width: 0;
  height:0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: width 2s, opacity 3.5s;
  float:left;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis culpa nobis dolorem voluptates ut odio numquam officia provident quos labore, natus sint doloribus ducimus similique aspernatur, enim, voluptatibus vel facere!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, adipisci? Quidem laboriosam sunt, qui non ea placeat laborum deserunt consequatur consequuntur vel, officiis magnam. Vitae officiis, quidem doloribus nesciunt voluptatem!
</p>
<span>Right side text</span>
```

But if you **have to** use `display:none`, then as shown in this [css article](https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2014/05/27/css-transitions-cant-animate-display-change/), you can just use the `setTimeout()` *workaround* to set the transition property **after** the display property is toggled instead of **during** the display property toggling like this:

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
p.style.display = "block";

setTimeout(function(){p.style.opacity = 1;},1000);
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum...
</p>
```

Comment: I wasn't really intending to use the `transition` property with the `display` property. I simply had the elements removed from the document flow, and put them back in before I did the `transition` on `opacity`.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281337/5221346). I think I discovered what's going on.

Comment: @Gendarme Using a `setInterval()` is a good idea too. You can use either approach for this.

Comment: That is indeed a nice trick. I never thought of that. `setInterval` could be a problem if those 100 milliseconds are too long, so this seems like a better workaround (if that is what one is looking for).

Comment: @Gendarme Agreed. I was just about to edit the answer with that alternative approach found in [this article](https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2014/05/27/css-transitions-cant-animate-display-change/) while searching for a way to do this with `display` just now myself.

Comment: I want to choose your answer as the accepted one, but you haven't really answered the question. I asked *why* this happens rather than looking for a workaround, and you simply stated *"You cannot use the `transition` property with the `display` property."* which doesn't really mean anything. I tried answering it in my own answer, but in the end it's just a hypothesis. Can you try to answer it? I will have to choose my own answer as the accepted one otherwise (since that would perfectly have answered the question even if written by someone else).

Comment: You can accept your own answer too mate. It's fine. I'll try searching for more info on this and will update my answer once I do. Cheers.